# Column Validation issue

Tags: sharepoint

I have a question on calculated columns.  I have looked up and down the net but have not been able to find a solution for this.

I have created a custom list and it has a field called "StartTime" which is a **Date and Time** field.  I am trying to do column validation on the field to prevent anyone from entering a Sat or Sun date.

I cannot figure out the formula to do this.

If I have a field called "TTime" and make it a **Date only** field and validate it with this formula: =AND(WEEKDAY(TTime)>1),(WEEKDAY(TTime)<7)) it works correctly.

I can break the Date and Time field down by the following formula: =DATE(YEAR(StartTime),MONTH(StartTime),DAY(StartTime))

I have no idea how to combine those 2 formulas together, so when someone chooses a Date and Time, it will not allow for Sat or Sun.  I have tried multiple ways to combine these 2 but always get an error when trying to save the changes to the field.

A workflow will not work as we want to prevent them from saving the record, so we are trying to validate before they can save it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this forumula:

```
=AND(WEEKDAY(DAY(DueDate))>1,(WEEKDAY(DAY(DueDate))<7))
```

This should work as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

Column validation won't get fired unless you fill all required fields first. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, the column validation formula also works for date and time field:

```
=AND(WEEKDAY(StartTime)>1,WEEKDAY(StartTime)<7)
```

You don't need to combine those 2 formulas together, just use the first formula would work for you.